# Combined Different Array with Fixed Length

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

If my Array1 is

```
Array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

the Result should be the same as Combined_Array= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

if i got

```
Array2=[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

the Resut should be Combined_Array =[1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15]

and if again i got

```
Array3=[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,19,30]
```

The Combined_array = [1,2,3,11,12,13,21,22,23,24]

and so on , Doesnt matter how much Array's i want that it should give me a Combined_Array from all the different Array with Fixed Length

Need a Function to make this work .

Comment: please add what does not work. why is `14` at last?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: My mistake .. it should be 24 at last ...

Comment: Do all the arrays you pass to function have same length? ie; 10 in this example?

Comment: yes .. all the Array will have same length i.e 10

Comment: "Need a Function to make this work" make one then, the problem you're trying to solve will teach you about functions, arrays, merging and sorting. If you're spoon-fed answers, you won't learn anything. Then, when you're struggling, come back and someone will be able to help you get back on track.

Comment: What if you have 20 arrays to combine? How would the combined array look then?

Comment: max array to be compined will be 10 ..

Comment: 10 what? Elements? Arrays?

Comment: Array .............................

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a closure over the collected arrays and retuen an array of the parts which are difined by the count of arrays.

```js
const
    getCombined = (a) => {
        const allArrays = [];

        return (b => {
            allArrays.push(b);
            let i = 0,
                p = Math.floor(10 / allArrays.length),
                result = [];

            while (i < allArrays.length) result.push(...allArrays[i++].slice(0, p));
            while (result.length < 10) result.push(allArrays[allArrays.length - 1][p++]);
            return result;
        });
    };

var c = [],
    add = getCombined(c);

c = add([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
console.log(...c); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

c = add([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]);
console.log(...c); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

c = add([21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]);
console.log(...c); // [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider many corner cases (if result array length exceeds given arrays count, if given arrays length differs and so on).
This will work for the simple scenario:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const arr2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
const arr3 = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 19, 30];

const combineArrays = (arr, length) => {
  let elementsCount = Math.floor(length / arr.length);

  const result = arr.reduce((acc, el) =>
    acc.concat(el.slice(0, elementsCount)), []);

  while (result.length < length)
    result.push(...arr.pop().slice(elementsCount, ++elementsCount));

  return result;
};

const result1 = combineArrays([arr1], 10); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const result2 = combineArrays([arr1, arr2], 10); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
const result3 = combineArrays([arr1, arr2, arr3], 10); // [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```